# I am getting wordpress mysql connection error using docker

Tags: mysql, linux, wordpress, docker

I created two docker containers using the commands below.

```
docker pull wordpress
docker pull mysql

docker run --name wordpress_database -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -d mysql

docker run --name wordpress_website --link wordpress_database:mysql -p 8080:80 -d wordpress
```

When I looked at the later logs, I encountered an error. Logs are below.
How do I prevent these errors?

***docker logs wordpress_website***

```
WordPress not found in /var/www/html - copying now...
Complete! WordPress has been successfully copied to /var/www/html
[15-Apr-2020 12:08:38 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli::__construct(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password] in Standard input code on line 22
[15-Apr-2020 12:08:38 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2054): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client in Standard input code on line 22

MySQL Connection Error: (2054) The server requested authentication method unknown to the client
[15-Apr-2020 12:08:41 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli::__construct(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password] in Standard input code on line 22
[15-Apr-2020 12:08:41 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2054): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client in Standard input code on line 22


WARNING: unable to establish a database connection to 'mysql'
  continuing anyways (which might have unexpected results)

AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Wed Apr 15 12:09:06.057462 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) PHP/7.3.16 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Apr 15 12:09:06.057505 2020] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
```

***docker logs wordpress_database***

```
2020-04-15 12:07:19+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.19-1debian10 started.
2020-04-15 12:07:20+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2020-04-15 12:07:20+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.19-1debian10 started.
2020-04-15 12:07:20+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
2020-04-15T12:07:20.102858Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
2020-04-15T12:07:20.102959Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.19) initializing of server in progress as process 43
2020-04-15T12:07:23.537919Z 5 [Warning] [MY-010453] [Server] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
2020-04-15 12:07:27+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Database files initialized
2020-04-15 12:07:27+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Starting temporary server
2020-04-15T12:07:27.774674Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
2020-04-15T12:07:27.774765Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.19) starting as process 93
2020-04-15T12:07:28.389657Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-04-15T12:07:28.397651Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2020-04-15T12:07:28.421413Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.19'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2020-04-15 12:07:28+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server started.
2020-04-15T12:07:28.457791Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock'
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone1970.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.

2020-04-15 12:07:30+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Stopping temporary server
2020-04-15T12:07:30.812504Z 10 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user root. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.19).
2020-04-15T12:07:32.529079Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.19)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2020-04-15 12:07:32+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server stopped

2020-04-15 12:07:32+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.

2020-04-15T12:07:33.133835Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
2020-04-15T12:07:33.133938Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.19) starting as process 1
2020-04-15T12:07:33.647310Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-04-15T12:07:33.652627Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2020-04-15T12:07:33.673452Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.19'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2020-04-15T12:07:33.812073Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '::' port: 33060
```

***localhost:8080***
Error establishing a database connection

Comment: Pls check if it is similar to docker-container [connection issue host db-server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61229854/4161807)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to publish ports to the host interface for MySQL container. Use this command to start the MySQL docker container:

```
docker run --name wordpress_database -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -d -p 3306:3306 mysql
```

Read [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports) for more details regarding publishing ports in a docker container.