# connect pandas in docker-gramex container, to database running on host machine using localhost

Tags: docker, gramex

after installing [docker-gramex](https://learn.gramener.com/guide/install/#docker-install) connecting app to database server running on host machine fails for connection URL: `'postgresql://db_user:db_passwd@localhost:5432/db_name'` 
throws `psycopg2.OperationalError could not connect to server: Connection refused`
Error persist even after making changes given in [blog-post](https://blog.jsinh.in/how-to-enable-remote-access-to-postgresql-database-server/)

Comment: similar, but different from scenario mentioned in [connecting to host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

Answer (score 1):

On AWS-EC2 with ubuntu, starting gramex using cmd:

`docker run --network=host \
               --name my-instance \
               -d -i -t -p 9998:9998 \
               -v "$(pwd)":"$(pwd)" -w "$(pwd)" \
               gramener/gramex`

it allows pandas to connect to postgresql server running on the host machine with the connection URL: `'postgresql://db_user:db_passwd@localhost:5432/db_name'`
param: `--network=host` makes it work.